# How to analytically compute $\iiint \frac{1}{\sqrt{a+b \sin c}}\,da\,db\,dc$

Tags: integration, closed-form

I'm wondering whether the following integral can be analytically computed:

$$\iiint\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+b \sin c}}\,da\,db\,dc$$

(Octave didn't yield any closed form associated with that.)

Edit: $c$ may vary between $0$ to $2\pi$ (unit circle), but $a$ and $b$ may vary in $R^{\ge 0}$.

Comment: What is the region of integration?

Comment: @PierreCarre: Please check the edit.

Comment: This most likely won't converge. For example given $b$ and $c$ constant in the inner integration with respect to $a$, the integrand behaves like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}$ and this integral diverges at infinity. Similarly you also have to worry about the fact that $a + b\sin c$ may become negative for many values of $a, b$ and $c$.

Comment: @TobErnack Regardless of the root-of-a-negative-number issue, is there a minimum exclusion of the cited region according to which the integral becomes convergent? For example, if one excludes $0$ off of both $a$ and $b$, would that let the integral converge?

Comment: The issue is more about the behavior at infinity. The function $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+b\sin c}}$ (where $b$ and $c$ are constant) has antiderivative $2\sqrt{a + b\sin c}$ and this is unbounded as $a$ goes to infinity. The singularity near $a+b\sin c = 0$ is actually integrable, but you'd still have to deal with defining the proper branch cut if you get into negative numbers.

Comment: @TobErnack: I see. May I simply consider $a+b\sin c > 0$ to catch that proper branch?

Comment: With `CAS` solution is by elliptic integrals if integral is indefine.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk: Can you provide some more details (such as which bounds are considered infinite)?

Comment: Mathematica code:`Integrate[Integrate[Integrate[1/Sqrt[a + b Sin[c]], a], b], 
  c] // FullSimplify` give me: `-((8 (b (a + b) EllipticE[1/4 (-2 c + \[Pi]), (2 b)/(a + b)] + 
    a (b EllipticF[1/4 (-2 c + \[Pi]), (2 b)/(a + b)] + 
       a EllipticPi[2, 1/4 (-2 c + \[Pi]), (2 b)/(a + b)])) Sqrt[(
  a + b Sin[c])/(a + b)])/(3 Sqrt[a + b Sin[c]]))`